# SymELAM.sys missing or corrupt Windows 8.1

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite e45t with Windows 8.1, and whenever I boot up, it says that SymELAM.sys is missing or corrupt. I read that it was related to Norton Anti-Virus, which I have. I've ran `chkdsk /r`. I also cannot boot into safe mode, either. Here is the error contents (it did not save a dmp file).:

```
Recovery

Your PC needs to be repaired

The operating system couldn't be loaded because a critical system driver is missing or contains errors.

File:\Windows\system32\drivers\NAVx64\1506000.020\SymELAM.sys
Error Code: 0xc000000f

You'll need to use the recovery tools on your installation media. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your system administrator or PC manufacturer.





Press Enter to try again
Press F8 for Startup Settings
Press Esc for UEFI Firmware Settings
```

I do have 2 recovery disks, a standard Windows 8.1 Recovery USB, and Hiren's Boot CD (on a usb). How do I fix this?

Comment: [0xc000000f = "STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE"](http://errlookup.azurewebsites.net/?err=0xc000000f) - Try getting a hold of a known-good copy of that file and put it where it's looking for it.  When you say you can't boot into Safe Mode, does it give you the same Stop error, or does something different happen?  When you ran `chkdsk`, did it report it found/fixed any errors?

Comment: It did find and fix errors. Can I download symELAM, or somehow make the OS stop looking for it?

Comment: I found a symelam.inf, but no sys file in that directory.

Comment: I can boot into windows with Early Launch Anti-

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I can get to the login screen with disabling Early Launch Anti-Malware , but then I randomly get IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL.

Comment: Does it matter much? From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-8.1-and-windows-server-2012-r2: "All editions of Windows 8.1 have reached end of servicing as of January 10, 2023." Consider installing a supported OS, whether Windows or Linux. Having Symantec antimalware suite on a Windows 8.1 machine gives a false sense of security.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse because I write in Spanish, but I don't know very much English, I resolved next way:

El archivo SYMELAM.SYS es un archivo creado por Norton, lo que hice fue copiar ese archivo de la carperta c:\Windows\system32\drivers\NAVx64\1506000.020\SymELAM.sys y crear en esa misma ruta, la carpeta a la cual el mensaje de error indicaba que me faltaba , en mi caso era \Windows\system32\drivers\NAVx64\160E020.00D\SymELAM.sys

Para hacer esto entre atravez de la linea de comandos "cmd" en la pantalla de recuperacion de windows 8.

Para mi eso fue la solucion, despues de hacer esto reinicie el equipo y listo funciono.

Espero les sea de utilidad.

In English:

The file SYMELAM.SYS is a file created by Norton, what I did was copy that file from the folder c:\Windows\system32\drivers\NAVx64\1506000.020\SymELAM.sys and create in that same path, the folder to which the error message indicated that I was missing, in my case it was C:\Windows\ system32\drivers\NAVx64\160E020.00D\SymELAM.sys

To do this, enter the command line "cmd" on the Windows 8 recovery screen.

For me that was the solution, after doing this, restart the computer and it worked.

I hope it will be useful to you!